# ERROR: canceling statement due to conflict with recovery

Tags: postgresql, replication

I got the error below:

```
ERROR: canceling statement due to conflict with recovery.
Detail: User query might have needed to see row versions that must be removed.;
nested exception in org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:ERROR:canceling statement due to conflict with recovery.
Detail: User query might have needed to see row versions that must be removed.
```

This error occurs on the standby, when we use long query.
We use PostgreSQL version 12.0. One master and two standby servers.

Could you please give us the solution?

Answer (score 6):

Some old row versions were removed by `VACUUM` on the primary server, but these row versions could still be required by the query on the standby.  So there is a conflict between the running query and the startup process applying changes that come from the primary.

PostgreSQL waits and delays replay for `max_standby_streaming_delay`, then cancels the query. So to avoid that problem, set `max_standby_streaming_delay` to -1 on the standby.

You can read more in [my blog](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/streaming-replication-conflicts-in-postgresql/).

Comment: After we  set max_standby_streaming_delay to -1 on the standby, will have any effect? Thanks

Comment: Yes. Don't forget to restart the standby.

Comment: thank you. I will try

Comment: Hi Laurenz,

When we set set max_standby_streaming_delay to -1, will it have some lag data on standby? I mean, will it not syn on time?

Comment: Yes, that will potentially delay the application of changes arbitrarily long.

Comment: hi sir @LaurenzAlbe how to set `max_standby_streaming_delay ` to -1? i'm just new in using postgresql

Comment: @pryxen Please read the PostgreSQL documentation about how to configure the server.

Comment: Docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/hot-standby.html#HOT-STANDBY-CONFLICT

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, try enabling `hot_standby_feedback=on` on the replica instance- this can be done with a reload command instead of restarting the database. This allows the Postgres replica to communicate back to the primary not to remove rows needed for query execution.

Beware that long running queries in your read replica may lead to table bloat in the primary since you are essentially disabling vacuuming on the rows that are needed for the query duration.